# event ID closest to specific hour

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a way to make a list with uniqeu event ID that has happened closed to a specific time.

There should only be one unique EVENT ID in the list that is closest to a specific time

For example tabel

```
Event ID     Time
Event 1     10:09
Event 2     09:00
Event 1     10:15
Event 3     07:12
Event 2     15:00
Event 3     13:15       
Event 1     18:00
```

requested result: for event closest to 15u

```
Event 1 10:15
Event 2 15:00
Event 3 13:15
```

What i tried to do was but LIMIT does not work in SQL

```
select Event ID 
from demo.table 
where time <=18:00 
order by event ID 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And when you say "closest", do you mean "closest before" or "closest after" or "closest before or after"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the closest even up-to-that time, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time) from t t2 where t2.eventid = t.eventid and t2.time <= '18:00')
```

This avoids date/time functions, should have reasonable performance, and should work in almost any database.